Sync Files from Salesforce to external drives like Gdirve or Onedrive
I'm developing a managed package and have a requirement to implement functionality that automatically uploads files attached on managed package object at regular intervals on some external drives like Gdrive or Onedrive. After researching, I find the following solution:

I will create a component into our package to obtain external drive credentials and save them in custom metadata.

I will create a batch job that runs periodically. Inside start method, it will obtain an access token and store it in a static class-level variable.

In execute method, the batch job will use this access token to upload files to the external drive.


Is this approach appropriate? What are its implications, and are there alternative approaches I should consider?

The main problem is going to be that Apex is limited to 12MB of heap memory in asynchronous code (e.g. batchable), which limits the sizes of the files that you could upload. The generally acceptable alternative is to develop a site hosted externally to act as a middleman between Salesforce and the third-party storage service. This would allow you to sync files up to 2GB in size. As a managed package solution, however, you'd have to take additional steps, such as a BURP scan, to ensure your middleware is sufficient secure against various attack vectors.

Thanks @sfdcfox, In my scenario, when user makes changes to a record, it triggers a call to an endpoint to retrieve a file. I can adjust my logic to initiate my batch process once I have received this file. so now I will upload these file just after I receive in my org. Do you think this approach will be effective as it will reduce n.o of file handle on a single call?
